# sphinx autofunction works fine on local but not on server

Tags: python-sphinx

The autofunction works perfectly on my local machine but on server it does not show anything. I check the log and find the following thing,
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import function blablabla; the following exception was raised: No module named 'numpy'.
I suppose installing packages is not a must on sphinx. I only need sphinx to read my docstring and generate documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after several hours of investigation I am able to answer my question. Using autodoc_mock_imports does the trick.